# Secure connection for retrofit2.0

Tags: android, https, retrofit, payment

I am getting error using retrofit2.0.

> Mixed Content: The page at
>   'https://demo.myvirtualmerchant.com/VirtualMerchantDemo/process.do'
>   was loaded over a secure connection, but contains a form which targets
>   an insecure endpoint
>       'http://********/******/***/*'. This endpoint should be made available over a secure connection.", source: 
>   https://demo.myvirtualmerchant.com/VirtualMerchantDemo/process.do (0)

i am using dependencies

```
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.0.2'    
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.0.2'    
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.4.1'
```

thanks in advance.